# The meaning of the code

Tags: bash, scripts

What is the code below means?

```bash
if ["$SHLVL" =1]: then
[-x /usr/bin/clear_console] && /usr/bin/clear_console -q
fi
```

Actually I'm trying to solve the problem in the picture:

[image]

Comment: you are missing spaces `if [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then` and it should be semicolon not colon

Comment: Sorry! I'm not a coder so...

Answer (score 1):

> `if ["$SHLVL" =1]: then`

the `SHLVL` variable tells you the number of shells deep you are (i.e. how many shells inside shells)

example:

```sh
$ echo $SHLVL
1

$ bash

$ echo $SHLVL
2

$ exit

$ echo $SHLVL
1
```

> `[-x /usr/bin/clear_console] &&`

checks if `/usr/bin/clear_console` exists and is executable.

> `/usr/bin/clear_console -q`

runs `/usr/bin/clear_console`, which just clears the terminal. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/clear_console.1.html.

> `fi`

ends the `if` condition

Comment: may it be the action that the villain do after finishing his job?

Comment: @ГеройНастоящий I didn't understand, could you clarify?

Comment: I mean, is the hacker may make such kind of code in order to avoid traces?

Comment: It will clear the console, so it is *possible* that a hacker *may* use it to cover something up, but this code is also perfectly useful for normal, non-hacker users.

Comment: Clearing the console isn't really going to hide anything though unless the user is watching the console, and then they could just scroll up.